# What order do you finish a room?

Tags: drywall, flooring, ceiling, finishing

My son and I are going to redo a small bedroom.  It currently has the thin faux wood siding on the walls usually in a mobile home and the ceiling actually has faux tile that would be normally on a bathroom wall.  The floor is awful, thin carpeting.  The outlets are halfway up the wall instead of down near the floor (not sure why).  So all of this is coming out and the outlets will be moved down to the proper location.  Once all that is done, What is the proper order to finish a room?

Top to bottom?  Ceiling sheet rock, then walls, then the flooring?  We are new to this, so we are not sure what is the order of finishing or why you would do it in a particular order?

Thanks in advance!  We are excited to take on the DIY project.

Comment: A word of caution on moving the receptacles. 1 - While the usual setup is lower down on the wall, there are times where higher up is better, particularly in a bedroom in order to be above the bed (whether for a phone or a lamp or whatever) instead of blocked by a bad; 2 - if the cables come up from the floor, no problem, but if the cables come down from the ceiling then you may have to run new cables because if you extend a cable then you need to put the connection in a junction box with a cover plate that is accessible - can't just throw the connection inside the wall.

Comment: Back when drywall was nailed, it was important to do the ceiling first so that the wall drywall holds up the perimeter. Now? Not really a big deal. I'm so messy with paint, drywall mud, etc. that I wouldn't do the floor until dead last.